# When to use C# out keyword on parameter

Tags: c#-4.0

I've seen some developers use the `out` keyword on parameter lists of void functions. I'm quite unclear on what the pros and cons are of code below:

```
List<string> listOfResult;    

public void public void (out listOfResult)
{
    //bla bla
}
```

versus

```
public List<string> c(out listOfResult)
{
    List<string>  list= new List<string>();
    //bla bla

    return list;
}
```

Are these two code snippets perfectly valid or is there any catch around the `out` keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`out` keyword is handy when you need to return more than one value from function. Nice example is `TryXXX` methods, which return status of operation instead of throwing exceptions:

```
public bool TryParse(string str, out int value);
```

But I don't see any reason to use single `out` parameter with void methods... Simply return that value from your method. It will be much easier to use. Compare:

```
List<string> list;
GetList(out list); // confusing method name
```

With

```
List<string> list = GetList(); // nice name, one line of code
```

If getting of list could throw exceptions, then you can create method like this:

```
List<string> list;
if (TryGetList(out list)) // better than exception handling
{
   // list was filled successfully
}
```

Answer (score 1):

out parameters are quite handy when you need to return more than one value from a function.

e.g.
Return is a list of results, but you can use an out parameter to return an error message in the case when the list being returned is null.

Answer (score 1):

It's a nice syntax to return multiple parameters. I personally think it's almost always better to model the return of the method as a "new object/class".

That would be:

```
class CResult
{
    List<string> firstResult;
    List<string> secondResult;
}

public CResult c()
{
    // do something
    return new CResult() {firstResult = ..., secondResult = ... };
}
```

You can see more things related to this approach [here](http://blogs.southworks.net/dgeffner/2011/08/08/object-oriented-algorithms/).

Answer (score 0):

//out key word is used in function instead of return. we can use multiple parameters by using out key word
public void outKeyword(out string Firstname, out string SecondName)
        {
            Firstname = "Muhammad";
            SecondName = "Ismail";

```
    }
```

//on button click Event
protected void btnOutKeyword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string first, second;
            outKeyword(out first, out second);
            lblOutKeyword.Text = first + "  " + second;
        }